# Git - Loosing file after renaming and branch, why?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I initialize a new repository in an empty folder:

```
git init
```

Now I copy two files A.java and B.java into this folder and commit:

```
git add A.java B.java && git commit -m "Added A.java and B.java to repo"
```

Next I create a new branch:

```
git branch newBranch
```

Afterwards I rename B.java to C.java (intentionally not using `mv`) and commit on the master branch. For git it is a deletion of B.java and a creation of C.java:

```
git add C.java && git commit -m "Renamed B.java to C.java"
```

Follow on I wanna switch to my newly created branch:

```
git checkout newBranch
```

When I take a look on my working directory now B.java will be gone and only A.java exists. Why? I did the branch before the second commit. I would expect that A.java and B.java are in their original state as when I executed the `branch` command. But obviously they are not and I don't understand why. Why is B.java gone?

Answer (score 1):

A `git status` should confirm it, but when you created your third commit, you only registered the creation of `C.java`.
You would have needed `git add B.java` to record the deletion of `B.java` from the history.

Since you did not, `B.java` remained deleted in the working tree.

Which means, switching to `newBranch` keep the working tree as is, with B.java deleted.

You can restore it with `git restore B.java`.

Comment: I still don't get it 100%. The first commit consisted of A and B. In my mind I see a snapshot on the hard drive with those two files. I understand that the deletion of B is considered a change. I did not stage this change. I only staged the new file C. For the next commit on the main branch I would expect A and B to be unchanged (since I didn't stage B) plus C. When I checkout the `newBranch` I would have expected that git takes the snapshot created first, looks into it and says "Ah, two files A and B".

Comment: " I did not stage this change. I only staged the new file C.": that is why. Again, git status should show B as still being deleted. And changing branch would not change that.